# Symmetrical, Transitional and Antisymmetrical question!

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $R \subseteq A \times A$ is it true that $R$ is symmetrical since $xRy$ then $yRx$ ?

I have written that this is also antisymmetrical if both $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ if $x =y$

How does I then make $R \subseteq A \times A$ transitive?

Comment: In English, it's called "transitive".

Answer (score 2):

You are either confused, or we are running against a language barrier (both are certainly possible).

It is not true that simply by virtue of being a subset of $A\times A$, a subset $R$ will be "symmetrical."

Rather: we define $R$ to be "symmetrical" **if and only if** for every $x$ and $y$ in $A$, *if* $(x,y)\in R$ (that is, if $xRy$), *then* $(y,x)\in R$ (that is, $yRx$).

An example of a symmetric relation on $\mathbb{R}$ is
$$R = \{ (a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \mid |a|=|b|\}$$
since, if $aRb$, then $|a|=|b|$, hence $|b|=|a|$, hence $bRa$.

An example of a non-symmetric relation on $\mathbb{R}$ is
$$S = \{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \mid a\geq 0\}.$$
It is not symmetric, because $(1,-1)\in S$, but $(-1,1)\notin S$.

We define $R$ to be "antisymmetric" **if and only if** for every $x$ and $y$ in $A$, **if** $xRy$ and $yRx$ are both true, **then** $x=y$.

(You have the implication reversed).

In the example $R$ above, $R$ is *not* antisymmetric, because $(1,-1)\in R$, $(-1,1)\in R$, but $-1\neq 1$.

However, an example of an antisymmetric relation on $\mathbb{R}$ is:
$$T = \{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\mid a\leq b\}.$$
This is antisymmetric because if $(a,b)\in T$ and $(b,a)\in T$, that means that $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$, so then we conclude that $a=b$.

Finally, a relation $R\subseteq A\times A$ is said to be "transitive" **if and only if** for every $a,b,c\in A$, *if* $aRb$ and $bRc$ both hold, then $aRc$ holds.

Both $R$, $S$, and $T$ above are transitive. To see an example of a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ that is not transitive, let
$$U = \{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\mid a\neq b\}.$$
Then $0U1$ holds, and $1U0$ holds, but $0U0$ does not hold. So $U$ is not transitive.

Comment: I think it was both language barrier, and I was confused by symmetric and antisymmetric meaning. It now makes more sense.  Its the small things like this that make the rest of the path. Thank you.